# Mapper Errors while creating Rows

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy

I'm working on building a recipe database. In this, there are ingredients (like onions, carrots, etc) and modifiers (like diced, peeled, etc) which are in part of ModifiedIngredients which is part of a recipe. My models.py is as follows:

```
from app import db

modifiers = db.Table('modifiers',
    db.Column('modified_ingredient', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('modified_ingredient.id')),
    db.Column('modifier', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('modifier.id'))
    )

modified_ingredients = db.Table('modified_ingredients',
    db.Column('recipe', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('recipe.id')),
    db.Column('modified_ingredient', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('modified_ingredient.id'))
    )

class Recipe(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'recipe'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

    name = db.Column(db.String(256))
    description = db.Column(db.Text)
    directions = db.Column(db.Text)
    prep_time = db.Column(db.Integer)
    cook_time = db.Column(db.Integer)
    image = db.Column(db.LargeBinary())
    ingredients = db.relationship('modified_ingredient', secondary=modified_ingredients)

class Ingredient(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'ingredient'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

    name = db.Column(db.String(30), index=True, unique=True)

class Modifier(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'modifier'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

    name = db.Column(db.String(30), index=True, unique=True)

class ModifiedIngredient(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'modified_ingredient'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

    amount = db.Column(db.Integer)
    unit = db.Column(db.String(20))
    ingredients = db.relationship('ingredient', backref='ingredient', lazy='dynamic')
    modifiers = db.relationship('Modifier', secondary=modifiers,
        backref=db.backref('modifiers', lazy='dynamic'), lazy='dynamic')
    recipe = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('recipe.id'))
```

However, if I open up a shell and enter in something like "`onion = models.Ingredient(name='Onion')`" I get the error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: One or more mappers failed to initialize - can't proceed with initialization of other mappers.  Original exception was: relationship 'ingredients' expects a class or a mapper argument (received: <class 'sqlalchemy.sql.schema.Table'>)
```

I'm not exactly sure where my setup is going wrong.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if i'm reading the error message correctly then

```
ingredients = db.relationship('modified_ingredient', secondary=modified_ingredients)
```

should become

```
ingredients = db.relationship('ModifiedIngredient', secondary=modified_ingredients)
```

Note in the error message:

> Original exception was: relationship 'ingredients' expects a class or a mapper argument (received: <class 'sqlalchemy.sql.schema.Table'>)

If it expects a class, give it a class :)